# what is this format specifier means %[^,] in C?

Tags: c, file-handling

i have a code snippet like this

```
while( fscanf(b,"%c,%[^,],%[^,],%f",&book.type,book.title,book.author,&book.price)!=EOF)
```

Comment: It means that it reads a string, but stops when it encounters a `,` character.

Comment: And then the comma which follows is used to match and read the comma that stopped it. Otherwise the next `%[^,]` and the `%f` would stall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading up on the format string part of [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

[image]

Specifically this part

> matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of characters. If
> the first character of the set is ^, then all characters not in the
> set are matched.

So, that format specifier matches all characters except the `,` character (which in your format string is matched afterward). So, if you had a struct like

```
typedef struct Book_t {
    char type;
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    float price;
}Book ;
```

and then had a file that had the data in the schema:

```
BookType,BookTitle,BookAuthor,BookPrice
```

Then once could possibly read in each line into `book` as

```
fscanf(b,"%c,%[^,],%[^,],%f",&book.type,book.title,book.author,&book.price)
```

For a line of the file as:

```
A,old man and the sea,ernest hemingway,12.5
```

`A` would be read into `book.type` and then all characters *not* matching a comma would be read, so that would read in till `sea` and stop since the next character is a `,`. This `,` would be matched with the `,` in the format string. The same process would repeat for the author field.

Note the caveat that reading in an unspecified number of characters till the matching stops before a comma is bad idea because the buffer that it's reading into is usually of a fixed length. That's why it's better to specify the maximum width (accounting for the null character) while doing so. Continuing with the above example, this would look something like

```
fscanf(b,"%c,%99[^,],%99[^,],%f",&book.type,book.title,book.author,&book.price)
```

To have the 99 denote that it should match only up to 99 characters at max to avoid any buffer overflows since the buffer `title` can hold only upto 100 characters and at least one byte would be required for the `\0` character.